# Dropdown menu is not showing aftre use overflow?

Tags: html, css

Drop down menu is not showing after using `overflow`. I want use overflow in div but its not working on hover.

Here's my code.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  }

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[You can see layout current show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD10D.png)
[I want to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yHQI.png)

Comment: What do you want? I did'nt understand

Comment: When i go to menu then dropdown menu is not show

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you have to set `overflow:scroll` to the button instead of giving overflow to the drop down content.

Try this.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow:scroll;
  }

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want use overflow in .dropdown class not .dropbtn

Comment: The screenshot you attached clearly shows the overflow is set to the button not for the `dropdown` content

Comment: You are right but i want use overflow css in .dropdown

Comment: can you share your contact number then i tell you clear about my question